# How to save temp image and then display it with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to save a png image as temp file and then display it with opencv, below code is what I have tried.

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import io
import numpy as np

overlay = cv2.imread('temp/CAM/0.png')
img = Image.fromarray(overlay.astype('uint8'))
file_object = io.BytesIO()
img.save(file_object, 'PNG')
file_object.seek(0)
file_object = np.array(file_object)

cv2.imshow('test', file_object)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-9c07b435fb51>", line 1, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('test', file_object)

TypeError: mat data type = 17 is not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
cv2.imshow('test', file_object)
```

you should use:

```
cv2.imshow('test', img)
```